# How can my friends test my Android application?

Tags: android, testing, apk

I am developing an Android application and it is not finished. I would like to test it on multiple devices, locations with various users that are not near me. How can I achieve this? Is there an APK I can send them? Is there a way that is as simple as plugging my phone in and then running the application from Eclipse? Or would I have to make an installer of some sort (I don't know)?

Comment: The generated APK you use for debugging can be sent to them. What development environment are you using?

Comment: Go to your folder  /bin/YourProject.apk is in there. They can upload it on a device and install it through file explorer or send them on Gmail and they can install it from there

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I'm Eclipse.

Comment: Bojan I would give you the correct answer if you answer since you replied first

Comment: From Android Studio, build and run the project. Then you should find the .apk file that you can share with your friends for them to test it. It should be in a location such as this one: C:\Users\jaimemontoya\Dropbox\[project_location]\[project_location]\[project_location]\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you can plug your phone(s) into the machine you are developing on and run it from eclipse. This will allow you to test and debug on the devices you have access to.

You can also export an apk from eclipse (see the android pages for instructions). You could put this up on a file sharing site and make it available to your friends. They could then install it, as long as they have authorised "unsigned" apks to be installed in their phone settings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have deployed the app at least once from within Eclipse to debug and test yourself, you will most likely have an APK under the bin directory in your Eclipse project. The file should be .apk. This APK will have been signed automatically by Eclipse with your debug key. This is obviously not the key you use for publishing but for testing among friends I think it's fine.

What I often do is just e-mail that APK file as an attachment to my friends to an e-mail account they have setup on their phone. Then all they need to do on their phone is make sure they have the system setting to allow installation of non-market apps (i.e. not from Google Play), which maybe named something slightly different like "allow 3rd party apps". Then they can simply click on the app attachment in their e-mail, download it and run it and they should automatically be prompted with instructions to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I just used [MyAppSharer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yschi.MyAppSharer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS55c2NoaS5NeUFwcFNoYXJlciJd). (I believe there are other similar apps out there - this is just the one I've used and is very simple/easy:

> ...you can share by market link or directly share APK (App's full
>   package)

I just used that, and sent my app via apk file to my coworkers.  Can't get much simpler.

Just install the app on your phone via Eclipse, then run this AppSharer, and voila - share it w/ anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can can easily export your project as an APK in eclipse

`File -> Export -> Export Android Project`